# What is a "barleycorn king"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

On "The Lady or the Tiger?" by Frank Stockton, it says:

> When a subject was accused of a crime of sufficient importance to
> interest the king, public notice was given that on an appointed day
> the fate of tile accused person would be decided in the king's
> arena,--a structure which well deserved its name; for, although its
> form and plan were borrowed -from afar, its purpose emanated solely
> from the brain of this man, who, **every barleycorn a king,** knew no
> tradition to which he owed more allegiance than pleased his fancy, and
> who ingrafted on every adopted form of human thought and action the
> rich growth of his barbaric idealism.

Barleycorn is a kind of corn or wheat as far as i understand.What did he mean when saying "every barleycorn king"?

Comment: A contributor to [this discussion](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/every-barleycorn-a-king.1485927/) claims: *My understanding is that barleycorn here is the old unit of measure, which was roughly a third of an inch. He was a king in every barleycorn, every centimetre of his person, so his will was law.* Another contributor writes: *Later, the author uses “its purpose emanated solely from the brain of this man, who, every barleycorn a king” to despise the king’s barbaric idea by shifting the angle of view and he also shows his denial attitude.*

Comment: Acually, exactly a third of an inch, since the definittion of an inch was "3 barleycorns"

Answer (score 2):

It's an unusual variant of *every inch a king*. See [Every inch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/every_inch) here.